# my custom list view crashes with an exception

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android, creating a custom list view with an image and text in each row. I had gone through many sites and did'nt get solved my issue. It crashes with an exception "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException" when navigating to my Activity. Please help. Thanks in advance.

My Avtivity LAyout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/myList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My customlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_column="9"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_column="19"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLength="28"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity Java

```
package com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Notify extends Activity {
String[] title = {"Business Meet","Personal meeting",
        "Meeting with doctor","Political meeting",
        "Meet for coffee","Dinner","Personal meeting",
        "Meeting with doctor","Political meeting"
};
int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.iconnew,R.drawable.button,
        R.drawable.nextbutton, R.drawable.iconnew,
        R.drawable.iconnew,R.drawable.button,
        R.drawable.iconnew,R.drawable.button,R.drawable.iconnew
};
ListView list;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public static final int UniqueId = 8984;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notify);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(imageId[0],title[0]));
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(imageId[1],title[1]));
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(imageId[2],title[2]));
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(imageId[3],title[3]));

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, rowItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
}
```

My CustomList.java

```
package com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomList(Context context, List<RowItem> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;

}

private class Holder{
    TextView textTitle;
    ImageView imageView;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;
    rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);
    }
    holder.textTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    holder.textTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageID());

    return rowView;
}
```

}

My RowItem.java

```
package com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar;
public class RowItem {
private  int imageID;
private String title;

public RowItem(int imageID, String title) {
    this.imageID = imageID;
    this.title = title;
}
public int getImageID(){
    return imageID;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
}
```

Activity declaration in Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Notify"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Log Cat

```
02-22 15:47:26.204 13538-13538/com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar, PID: 13538
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2365)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:949)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at com.example.pramodpmk.smartcalendar.CustomList.getView(CustomList.java:35)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2339)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your log cat output please

Comment: When you know it *crashes with an exception* still you haven't posted the logcat error trace. That is the most important piece of puzzle right now.

Comment: kindly post your xml layout used in the CustomAdapter ?

Comment: @apmartin1991 posted my logcat bro. I'm running my app to phone, not on emulator.

Comment: Are your uploading right customlist.xml? The xml for the custom list and activity is same in your post.

Comment: @PramodMoolekandathil: You are using wrong layout in `getView` method.

Comment: @PramodMoolekandathil you are using the wrong layout in the adapter. If you use the correct one the error will be clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right

```
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);
```

`customlist` xml contains a listview. You need to use a xml which has `R.id.textView8` and `R.id.imageView4` in it.

**Update**

Also remove `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`

Comment: Try removing `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`

Comment: It worked , removing super.getView(position, convertView, parent); Thanks bro

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your customlist.xml

The problem is that you are inflating with custom list layout and it does not have any view with textView8, imageView4 id.

Try replacing with this:

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter trying to load the default layout resource for `ArrayAdapter`.
Try remove the line

```
super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

from the getView method in your `CustomList` class

Answer (score 0):

First cross check all the Images are present in drawable folder, second alter your code refering to my below code.

```html
//change height of listview to android:layout_height="match_parent"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/myList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```html
/use holder class properly for one time component initialization.
//its better to instantiate LayoutInflater object in Adapter Constructor itself for one time initialization.
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 Holder holder =null;
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View row = convertView ;
if(row  == null){
 row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);
 holder = new Holder();
 row.setTag(holder);
}else{
holder  = (Holder )row.getTag();
}
 
    holder.textTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageID());

    return rowView;


}
```

```html
//alter your holder class by refering below class.
private class Holder{
    TextView textTitle;
    ImageView imageView;

public Holder(View v){
textTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
imageView = (ImageView )v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

}

}
```